# How to export data from grid to other grid on other page?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi  i have application where i have to export grid data on a page to another grid on other page..

my logic is i have grid with check boxes.........and i have an admin and 3 users...i have one page for "admin" and one page for other "3 users" when they login they are taken to thier own page.....when admin logins he has the grid filled with data with check boxes.......

```
       1)now the "admin" logins and visits his page his page looks like this
        he has a button called assign work and a dropdownlist binded with three users                      names.
       2)The admin selects some data using checkbox and selects the username from the dop down list ,and clicks on assign work button.
        3)In the same way he does for other two users....
       4)Here all the users have same page when user 1 logins he should be seeing only the  work assigned to him by admin,when user two logins his work should be shown.
```

can any 1 tell me how to start this...how should i prepare the database and use that....
and can any provide me the required code...will be helpfull to me...

thanks in advance guys...

Comment: Why you want to export grid data to another page? In another page, you can load data that you want after data in first grid data is updated into DB.

Comment: the admin assigns the data to the user...the assigned data will be shoen to the user in a grid@ThitLwinOo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference, please check the following. It is not perfect solution, need to modify some referential integrity, etc. Just provide you some idea for your requirements.

-- DB design

```
-- user information
create table USERS (USER_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, USER_NM NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
insert into USERS values ('Admin');
insert into USERS values ('User 1');
insert into USERS values ('User 2');
insert into USERS values ('User 3');

-- role description
create table ROLES_DESC (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL, ROLE_DESC NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO ROLES_DESC VALUES (1,'Admin');
INSERT INTO ROLES_DESC VALUES (2,'User');

-- assing each user to at least one role
create table ROLES (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, USER_ID INT NOT NULL, ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL)
insert into ROLES (1,1) -- admin
insert into ROLES (2,2) -- User 1
insert into ROLES (3,2) -- User 2
insert into ROLES (4,2) -- User 3


-- task infomration
create table TASKS (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, TASK_DESC VARCHAR(100))
insert into TASKS values ('C# Programming');
insert into TASKS values ('Database Programming');
insert into TASKS values ('Match Homework');


-- admin can assing task to each user.. save here
create table ASSINGMENTS (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, USER_ID INT NOT NULL, TASK_ID INT NOT NULL, ASSING_DT DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())
insert into ASSINGMENTS (USER_ID,TASK_ID) values (2,1);
insert into ASSINGMENTS (USER_ID,TASK_ID) values (2,2);
insert into ASSINGMENTS (USER_ID,TASK_ID) values (3,1);
insert into ASSINGMENTS (USER_ID,TASK_ID) values (4,3);
```

---------in aspx you have admin page and user page
In admin page, use templatefiled columns (user dropdown and task dropdown )
for User dropdown

```
SELECT USER_ID, USER_NM) FROM USERS WHERE ID <> 1 -- (only select non-admin user)
```

for task drop down list

```
SELECT ID, TASK_DESC FROM TASKS
```

-- when update task to each user event, read data from grid and save into ASSINGMENTS table

For User Page --

Just read data from ASSINGMENTS table join with USERS , TASKS tables as follow and bind to gridview

```
SELECT A.TASK_ID, T.TASK_DESC, A.ASSING_DT
FROM ASSINGMENTS A
INNER JOIN TASKS T ON (A.TASK_ID = T.ID)
WHERE A.USER_ID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your database and your schema.
You should create an `Work` table that contains

- ID int
- CreatedBy (admin ID)
- CreatedAt datetime
- Subject and/or Remarks varchar null

Then i would use 1-n relation-table `WorkAssignment` that stores the user-assignement and the data that was chosen by the admin(what should be done)

- ID int
- fiWorker (id of the assigned user)
- fiWork (id of the record in `Work`)
- Subject and/or Remarks varchar null (if you later want to leave a remark for this user)
- fiData int (links to the record of your GridView)

Comment: Do i have to save the selected data in a single coulmn called createdby(adminId).@Tim Schmelter

Comment: `CreatedBy` is only the column which stores the user-ID of the admin that assigns the work. Even when there is only one person now, that might change in future(f.e. a worker may be able to assign work to other workers as well). So it's generally a good idea to store it. `fiData` in table `WorkAssignment` is the column which refers to the selected item in the GridView. (Btw, a better name would be `AssignedBy` and `AssignedAt`)